# facing problems in solving the below issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Owl Carousel</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="owl-carousel">
            <div> Your Content </div>
            <div> Your Content </div>
            <div> Your Content </div>
            <div> Your Content </div>
            <div> Your Content </div>
            <div> Your Content </div>
            <div> Your Content </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
            });
        </script>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to use owl carousel in my new project but it seems the owl carousel isn't working, i have tried with the above code dont know where im going wrong please can any one help me so that it will help me to fix the issue, since im new to this field im unable to solve the issue,please can any one help me out in this

Comment: you JS code after the jQuery include

Comment: Hello , I’m having trouble understanding your question. can you please change your question topic and please add question description clearly

Comment: did not got you sir please can you bit more specific please

Comment: @core114 im trying to make the owl carousel work but i facing problem in getting it work please see the code which i have tried please can u help me

Comment: @pavankumar check the Bhargav Chudasama's answer

Comment: @core114 ya i got it thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove `<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>` from last

and initialize Carousel like below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  });
});
```

or try this code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Owl Carousel</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
    <div> Your Content </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @bhargav ur answer works but one issue im facing if i reduce my one div for example i want to use only 3 divs then ur code isn't working

Comment: i didn't understand what you say?

Comment: consider for example im using only 3 <div>content</div> then ur code wont work, if i use 6 or more  <div>content</div> then only ur above works

Comment: i have try in my code with 3 div `content` its work fine you also try in my answer remove other div only 3 div there and run its working

Comment: ok that works if i reduce my browser size what if i want to display div one after the other on all the screen size